# Exception handling over multiple calling levels

Tags: python, exception, try-except

How do you best handle multiple levels of methods in a call hierarchy that raise exceptions, so that if it is a fatal error the program will exit (after displaying an error dialog)?

I'm basically coming from Java. There I would simply declare any methods as `throws Exception`, re-throw it and catch it somewhere at the top level.

However, Python is different. My Python code basically looks like the below.

**EDIT:** added much simpler code...

Main entry function (`plugin.py`):

```
def main(catalog):

    print "Executing main(catalog)... "
    # instantiate generator
    gen = JpaAnnotatedClassGenerator(options)

    # run generator
    try:
        gen.generate_bar()  # doesn't bubble up
    except ValueError as error:
        Utilities.show_error("Error", error.message, "OK", "", "")
        return

    ... usually do the real work here if no error
```

`JpaAnnotatedClassGenerator` class (`engine.py`):

```
class JpaAnnotatedClassGenerator:

    def generate_bar(self):
        self.generate_value_error()

    def generate_value_error(self):
        raise ValueError("generate_value_error() raised an error!")
```

I'd like to return to the caller with an exception that is to be thrown back to that ones call until it reaches the outermost `try-except` to display an error dialog with the exception's message.

**QUESTION**:
How is this best done in Python? Do I really have to repeat `try-except` for every method being called?

BTW: I am using Python 2.6.x and I cannot upgrade due to being bound to MySQL Workbench that provides the interpreter (Python 3 is on their upgrade list).

Comment: No need to write `Python: ` in the headline. Tagging it with Python is plenty enough. Not sure why no one has said this to you before. I see you've done this in at least every other question you've asked. This is the reason why I'm mentioning it.

Comment: Maybe. My hope was that search engines could better differentiate between questions belonging to a language if it was not hidden in some tag. After all, Java is mentioned as well. I'm not a SEO expert though

Comment: Not sure if this will help in your use case, but I think the equivalent of a parameter on the function, as in java, would be to define a function decorator that raises the exception and apply that to your functions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597683/python-decorator-that-lets-method-run-or-raise-an-exception

Comment: Take note that ``Generator`` is an inbuilt (function) type in Python. Reusing the name is likely to confuse maintainers.

Comment: I renamed the class when posting this question. The actual class name is `JpaAnnotatedClassGenerator`. See edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't catch an exception, it bubbles up the call stack until someone does. If no one catches it, the runtime will get it and die with the exception error message and a full traceback. IOW, you don't have to explicitely catch and reraise your exception everywhere - which would actually defeat the whole point of having exceptions. Actually, despite being primarily used for errors / unexpected conditions, exceptions are first and foremost a control flow tool allowing to break out of the normal execution flow and pass control (and some informations) to any arbitrary place up in the call stack.

From this POV your code seems mostlt correct (caveat: I didn't bother reading the whole thing, just had a quick look), except (no pun indented) for a couple points:

First, you should define your own specific exception class(es) instead of using the builtin ValueError (you can inherit from it if it makes sense to you) so you're sure you only catch the exact exceptions you expect (quite a few layers "under" your own code could raise a ValueError that you didn't expect).

Then, you may (or not, depending on how your code is used) also want to add a catch-all top-level handler in your `main()` function so you can properly log (using the `logger` module) all errors and eventually free resources, do some cleanup etc before your process dies.

As a side note, you may also want to learn and use proper string formatting, and - if perfs are an issue at least -, avoid duplicate constant calls like this:

```
elif AnnotationUtil.is_embeddable_table(table) and AnnotationUtil.is_secondary_table(table):
    # ...
elif AnnotationUtil.is_embeddable_table(table):
    # ...
elif AnnotationUtil.is_secondary_table(table):
    # ...
```

Given Python's very dynamic nature, neither the compiler nor runtime can safely optimize those repeated calls (the method could have been dynamically redefined between calls), so you have to do it yourself.

EDIT:

> When trying to catch the error in the main() function, exceptions DON'T bubble up, but when I use this pattern one level deeper, bubbling-up seems to work.

You can easily check that it works correctly with a simple MCVE:

```
def deeply_nested():
    raise ValueError("foo")

def nested():
    return deeply_nested()

def firstline():
    return nested()

def main():
    try:
        firstline()
    except ValueError as e:
        print("got {}".format(e))
    else:
        print("you will not see me")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

> It appears the software that supplies the Python env is somehow treating the main plugin file in a wrong way. Looks I will have to check the MySQL Workbench guys

Uhu... Even embedded, the mechanism expection should still work as expected - at least for the part of the call stack that depends on your `main` function (can't tell what happens upper in the call stack). But given how MySQL treats errors (what about having your data silently truncated ?), I wouldn't be specially suprised if they hacked the runtime to silently pass any error in plugins code xD

Comment: You are correct. I'm only using `ValueError` because I had other problems to attend than defining a custom `PluginError` at the time. I deferred that up until the problem described in my question would take some priority. ;-) And yes, the code you posted, I will optimize the calls to `AnnotationUtil.is_*()`. *yuk*

Comment: I stumbled accross a hard-to-find bug in my code. Thanks for helping with explaining how exceptions are handled in Python.

Answer (score 4):

## It is fine for errors to bubble up

Python's exceptions are unchecked, meaning you have no obligation to declare or handle them. Even if you know that something may raise, only catch the error if you intend to do something with it. It is fine to have exception-transparent layers, which gracefully abort as an exception bubbles through them:

```
def logged_get(map: dict, key: str):
    result = map[key]  # this may raise, but there is no state to corrupt
    # the following is not meaningful if an exception occurred
    # it is fine for it to be skipped by the exception bubbling up
    print(map, '[%s]' % key, '=>', result)
    return result
```

In this case, `logged_get` will simply forward any `KeyError` (and others) that are raised by the lookup.
If an outer caller knows how to handle the error, it can do so.

So, just call `self.create_collection_embeddable_class_stub` the way you do.

## It is fine for errors to kill the application

Even if nothing handles an error, the interpreter does. You get a stack trace, showing what went wrong and where. Fatal errors of the kind "only happens if there is a bug" can "safely" bubble up to show what went wrong.

In fact, exiting the interpreter and assertions use this mechanism as well.

```
>>> assert 2 < 1, "This should never happen"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError: This should never happen
```

For many services, you can use this even in deployment - for example, `systemd` would log that for a Linux system service. Only try to suppress errors for the outside if security is a concern, or if users cannot handle the error.

## It is fine to use precise errors

Since exceptions are unchecked, you can use arbitrary many *without* overstraining your API. This allows to use custom errors that signal different levels of problems:

```
class DBProblem(Exception):
    """Something is wrong about our DB..."""

class DBEntryInconsistent(DBProblem):
    """A single entry is broken"""

class DBInconsistent(DBProblem):
    """The entire DB is foobar!"""
```

It is generally a good idea not to re-use builtin errors, unless your use-case actually matches their meaning. This allows to handle errors precisely if needed:

```
try:
    gen.generate_classes(catalog)
except DBEntryInconsistent:
    logger.error("aborting due to corrupted entry")
    sys.exit(1)
except DBInconsistent as err:
    logger.error("aborting due to corrupted DB")
    Utility.inform_db_support(err)
    sys.exit(1)
# do not handle ValueError, KeyError, MemoryError, ...
# they will show up as a stack trace
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood you and bruno correctly, but the problem at hand is, that a call to the nested function `create_collection_embeddable_class_stub(...)` does NOT "bubble up" to the `try-except` of the `main()` function. I just tried it. See line 19 of the 2nd code box, in the part `elif AnnotationUtil.is_embeddable_table(table): ... embeddable_class = self.create_collection_embeddable_class_stub(table, self.common_table_prefix)`

Comment: @Kawu Exceptions from nested functions *do* bubble up. That is how Python works. I am afraid your code is way too extensive to trace what is going on in detail. Are you sure the exception is actually thrown, i.e. the code path reached?

Comment: This is strange. I just tried something. When trying to catch the error in the `main()` function, exceptions DON'T bubble up, but when I use this pattern one level deeper, bubbling-up seems to work. It appears the software that supplies the Python env is somehow treating the main plugin file in a wrong way. Looks I will have to check the MySQL Workbench guys...

Comment: Ah. Finally found the issue. Code logic problems. Sometimes not being able to use a debugger is tough. Thanks for helping.